# In VBA copy all worksheet data to a specific sheet in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy

Please help. Been looking at this and searching sites for 2 days. I have a file that is the summary file "mysumwb." I am opening all files in a folder. "LsWb" represents the open file. Searching for a particular sheet named "LsFileSh." and copy/paste value of the entire sheet "LsFileSh" into the last sheet in the summary file. What is actually happening is the sheet is being copied onto **ALL** of the sheets in the target/summary file "mysumwb."

Here is the code. Sorry for all the comments. And thank you.

```
 Sub Summarize_Reports()
'Mar 18, 2019
On Error Resume Next

Const shN = "Sheet Format"                               '<< summary workbook sheet name
Const LsFileSh = "1. Summary for Reporting "             '<< summary workbook sheet name

Dim wb As Workbook
Set mysumwb = ThisWorkbook                               '<< The summary WB
Dim SumWs As Worksheet
Set SumWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shN)                     '<< The summary workbook sheet, "Summary Format"


Dim CountSh As Long, r As Long, c As Long
Dim A As Long
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim LsWb As Workbook        '<< This is the leasing file WB identifierDim fldr As FileDialog
Dim LsFileName As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'***********************************This With statement selects the folder

Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
.Title = "Please select the folder where the Capital lease files are, then press OK to continue"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then
    Set fldr = Nothing
    Else
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    If Right(myPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    myPath = myPath & "\"
    End If
End With

myFile = Dir(myPath & "*capital*.xl*")

'MsgBox mysumwb.Name
'MsgBox mysumwb.Worksheets.Count
CountSh = mysumwb.Worksheets.Count
'MsgBox CountSh

Do While myFile <> ""


    Sheets("Summary Format").Select                      '<<<<<< copy the tab in the sumwp file
    Sheets("Summary Format").Copy After:=Sheets(CountSh)

    'mysumwb.SumWs.Select
    'mysumwb.SumWs.Copy After:=mysumwb.workheets(CountSh)

    Set LsWb = Workbooks.Open(myPath & myFile)           '<<< establish the open leasing file's name
    LsFileName = Left(LsWb.Name, Len(LsWb.Name) - 4)     '<<< move the filename to a string
    mysumwb.Sheets(CountSh + 1).Name = LsFileName

    LsWb.Sheets(LsFileSh).Activate
 '   LsWb.Sheets(LsFileSh).Cells.Copy
 '   mysumwb.Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Cells.Value = LsWb.Sheets(LsFileSh).Cells.Value

    With mysumwb

        CountSh = mysumwb.Worksheets.Count
        MsgBox CountSh
        .Sheets(CountSh).Name = LsFileName
        .Sheets(LsFileName).Activate
        .Sheets(LsFileName).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        MsgBox LsFileName
    End With

'    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name
'    mysumwb.Sheets(LsFileName).Select
'    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(CountSh + 1).Name
'
'
'
'    mysumwb.Sheets(LsFileName).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


    Application.CutCopyMode = False


    LsWb.Close False
    myFile = Dir()
    mysumwb.Save
Loop


ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
NoFilesProcessed.Value = "Lease Files Processed = " & A
MsgBox A
MsgBox "All Done!"


On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Edit your question

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the below code and it works for me. The way you use on error resume next is not a good idea since your code return lots of error. I removed it and fixed the error and my own test run is successful.
if you run the code let me know if you encounters any error. and what the error is.

```
Sub Summarize_Reports()
'Mar 18, 2019


Const shN = "Sheet Format"                               '<< summary workbook sheet name
Const LsFileSh = "1. Summary for Reporting "             '<< summary workbook sheet name

Dim wb As Workbook
Set MySumWb = ActiveWorkbook                               '<< The summary WB
Dim SumWs As Worksheet
Set SumWs = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(shN)                     '<< The summary workbook sheet, "Summary Format"


Dim CountSh As Long, r As Long, c As Long
Dim A As Long
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim LsWb As Workbook        '<< This is the leasing file WB identifierDim fldr As FileDialog
Dim LsFileName As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'***********************************This With statement selects the folder

Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
.Title = "Please select the folder where the Capital lease files are, then press OK to continue"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then
    Set fldr = Nothing
    Else
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    If Right(myPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    myPath = myPath & "\"
    End If
End With

myFile = Dir(myPath & "*capital*.xl*")

'MsgBox mysumwb.Name
'MsgBox mysumwb.Worksheets.Count
CountSh = MySumWb.Worksheets.Count
'MsgBox CountSh

Do While myFile <> ""


    MySumWb.Worksheets("Summary Format").Select                      '<<<<<< copy the tab in the sumwp file
    MySumWb.Worksheets("Summary Format").Copy After:=Sheets(CountSh)

    'mysumwb.SumWs.Select
    'mysumwb.SumWs.Copy After:=mysumwb.workheets(CountSh)

    Set LsWb = Workbooks.Open(myPath & myFile)           '<<< establish the open leasing file's name
    LsFileName = Left(LsWb.Name, Len(LsWb.Name) - 4)     '<<< move the filename to a string
    MySumWb.Sheets(CountSh + 1).Name = LsFileName

    LsWb.Sheets(LsFileSh).Activate
    LsWb.Sheets(LsFileSh).Cells.Copy

    MySumWb.Sheets(LsFileName).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues



'    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name
'    mysumwb.Sheets(LsFileName).Select
'    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(CountSh + 1).Name
'
'
'
'    mysumwb.Sheets(LsFileName).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


    Application.CutCopyMode = False


    LsWb.Close False
    myFile = Dir()
    MySumWb.Save
Loop


ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox A
MsgBox "All Done!"



End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you , but it is still pasting values over all sheets. I am not having a problem with any part of the code (messy as it is) except for the pasting over all sheets. Please help me with that.

Comment: Hi - I am getting a runtime error 9. subscript out of range error.

Comment: Could you tell which line? The way I remove On error resume next is assuming all those sheet names are existed in those excel files. if they are not the case you can add the On error resume next back to the code.

Comment: Hi Peicong, All of the workbooks have that sheet.  I think this is the line with the error:   LsWb.Sheets(LsFileSh).Activate

Comment: Hi Peicong, First - THANK YOU for your patience and spending the time with me. IT WORKS!!! I am not quite sure what you changed, but it's working now. I will clean up my code and move on to the next one. Have a great evening!!

Comment: Much appreciate if you like my solution and upvote my answer. :)